# Bliss bug? Automorphism group generators depend on branching heuristic

Tags: igraph

I'm trying to use [Bliss](http://www.tcs.hut.fi/Software/bliss/) to compute the automorphism group generators of a graph. I thought I'd rather ask here on SO before I bother the auther with "bug", which is actually just my fault.

One of the options of bliss is the branching heuristic, which specifies which cell (of a partition of the vertices) is considered next.

e.g.

- `f` means First non-unit cell.
- `fs` means First smallest non-unit cell.
- `fsm` means First smallest maximally non-trivially connected non-unit cell.
  etc.

This graph gives me a headache: http://pastebin.com/Ppq7N1mN (file format: http://www.tcs.hut.fi/Software/bliss/fileformat.shtml)

Surprisingly, the numbers of generators differ for different branching heuristics... The modes `f`, `fl` return 2 generators, but I think there are 3, which `fs`,`fm`,`fsm` and `flm` confirm.

It's weird that the automorphism group size matches `|Aut|=8`. I checked why, and somehow bliss thinks that the orbit of one of the generators has size 4 and thus calculates the order 2*4=8. I don't exactly know how the algorithm works nor do I understand the code well enough so that I could find a bug.

So my question is: Am I missing something and this behaviour is normal or is that a bug in the library?

And here's the output. That the canonical labellings are different is expected!

```
bliss -directed -can -sh=f test.dimacs
Generator: (2,4)(10,18)(11,20)(12,19)(13,21)(40,76)(41,77)(42,78)(43,79)(44,80)(45,81)(46,82)(47,83)(48,84)(49,85)(50,86)(51,87)(52,88)(53,89)(54,90)(55,91)(56,92)(57,93)
Generator: (1,2)(3,4)(6,10)(7,11)(8,13)(9,12)(14,18)(15,20)(16,21)(17,19)(22,43)(23,42)(24,41)(25,40)(26,57)(27,56)(28,55)(29,54)(30,53)(31,52)(32,51)(33,50)(34,49)(35,48)(36,47)(37,46)(38,45)(39,44)(58,79)(59,78)(60,77)(61,76)(62,93)(63,92)(64,91)(65,90)(66,89)(67,88)(68,87)(69,86)(70,85)(71,84)(72,83)(73,82)(74,81)(75,80)(94,95)
Canonical labeling: (1,4)(6,20,14,21)(7,16,8,9,12,11,15,17,13)(10,19)(22,77,66,24,68,30,25,73,88,90,39,44,43,75,45,29,41,67,92,54,40,71,51,32,33,49,83,34,85,82,86,46,87,31,93,64,80,42,61,72,37,89)(23,58,76,70,84,52,91,78,60,69,48,53)(26,62,63,57,65,38)(27,56,55,79,74)(28,81)(35,50,47)
Nodes:          6
Leaf nodes:     4
Bad nodes:      0
Canrep updates: 1
Generators:     2
Max level:      2
|Aut|:          8
Total time:     0.06 seconds

bliss -directed -can -sh=fsm test.dimacs
Generator: (2,4)(10,18)(11,20)(12,19)(13,21)(40,76)(41,77)(42,78)(43,79)(44,80)(45,81)(46,82)(47,83)(48,84)(49,85)(50,86)(51,87)(52,88)(53,89)(54,90)(55,91)(56,92)(57,93)
Generator: (1,3)(6,14)(7,15)(8,16)(9,17)(22,58)(23,59)(24,60)(25,61)(26,62)(27,63)(28,64)(29,65)(30,66)(31,67)(32,68)(33,69)(34,70)(35,71)(36,72)(37,73)(38,74)(39,75)
Generator: (1,2)(3,4)(6,10)(7,11)(8,13)(9,12)(14,18)(15,20)(16,21)(17,19)(22,43)(23,42)(24,41)(25,40)(26,57)(27,56)(28,55)(29,54)(30,53)(31,52)(32,51)(33,50)(34,49)(35,48)(36,47)(37,46)(38,45)(39,44)(58,79)(59,78)(60,77)(61,76)(62,93)(63,92)(64,91)(65,90)(66,89)(67,88)(68,87)(69,86)(70,85)(71,84)(72,83)(73,82)(74,81)(75,80)(94,95)
Canonical labeling: (1,2,4,3)(6,21,8,7,15,14,20,16)(9,13)(10,19)(11,17,12)(22,75,42,59,60,66)(23,61,72,34,83,36,35,53,25,73,86,48,51,31,93,62,64,80,44,45,27,55,79,76,70,82,88,90,38,29,41,69,46,89,24,67,92,56,57,63,54,39,43,77,68,32,33,47,37,87,30)(26,65,40,71,52,91,78,58,74,28,81)(49,85,84,50)(94,95)
Nodes:          9
Leaf nodes:     4
Bad nodes:      0
Canrep updates: 1
Generators:     3
Max level:      3
|Aut|:          8
Total time:     0.06 seconds
```

I didn't know how to tag this question, so I chose igraph - [a library that uses bliss for this problem](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#canonical_permutation).

Comment: But the size of two minimal generating sets doesn't necessarily need to be the same.  E.g. for the group of integers module 10, both {1} and {2,5} are minimal generating sets.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps this should have been asked on Math.SE?  It's not a programming question, but a mathematics one. You are asking if Bliss's result is correct.  `igraph` is really not an appropriate tag there as igraph doesn't even expose this functionality of Bliss.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine suggested that the generating set of the second method might not be minimal. And indeed you can get the missing generator from the other two:

```
(1 2)(3 4)...  *  (2 4)(10 18)...  *  (1 2)(3 4)...  =  (1 3)(6 14)...
```